# android - save parts of streaming videos

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, gstreamer

I want to create an app which record video from camera, and while video recording save pieces of this streaming - length is 30 second. And when recording will stop I will have a lot of video files - each duration 30 seconds. 

Is it possible to do in Android? If yes - what libraries or methods use for this task?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do in Android?

Yes. it is possible

> what libraries or methods use for this task?

1)MediaRecorder. it is android framework API.

2)MediaCodec + MediaMuxer. also framework APIs.

with second option you will have more control but is complex to implement. while first option is relatively straight forward. but with first option you wont be able to create video clips that is continuous. as stopping and starting a MediaRecorder isn't instantaneous.

Comment: now I record video use intent, in your method I must use MediaRecorder or MediaCodec for rercord, right? Thank you)

Comment: yes, recording via intent redirect to other app over which you have no control.